# QGIS python plugins: How to install python packages, f.e. cx_Oracle

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

I want to develop a python- plugin for QGIS. For this I need to install packages (f.e. cx_Oracle) on my computer and of course - when deployed on client- computers.
Can anyone tell me, how to do this, preferably without the need for admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

```
import sys
import subprocess

def Package_Install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])
```

You can install ***Python*** packages using the OS shell. The `sys.executable` gets the ***Python*** interpreter used by the application, and the rest of the variables are command line arguments. You will not need administrator privileges because this operation will require the same level of privileges as the ***Python*** application.

## Result

[image: Script terminal output]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This sounds as needed. Problem: If I start Package_Install('cx_Oracle) I get the error "C:\Users\Default\Documents\cx_Oracle" ist keine gültige Datenquelle oder wird nicht erkannt." There is  of course no cx_Oracle. How can I specify where cx_Oracle is to be found?

Comment: The problem seems to be that it installs the cx_Oracle library inside the Documents directory. Python dependencies should be installed inside the directory where the Python interpreter for the current Python virtual environment is located.

Comment: Or are you manually selecting the Documents directory?

Comment: Check my modified answer

Comment: Thank you. I tried many things and found out: If I install using pip inside an virtual environment, it is installed inside the environment. No matter what I specify. If I install it w/o using Virtual Environment, it is installed into the documents folder. It seems to be different, if python is installed "for all users" or as admin (this option I do not have, if the admin installs it, I if course can not use this). QGIS is installed by the admin, so my pip goes to the documents folder. The "used" solution is: Install it anywhere and set the path to this location inside the QGIS- Plugin. Dirty:(

Answer (score 1):

For background info, cx_Oracle was replaced by python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

You can generally install Python packages without needing admin privileges by using the pip option `--user`.  To install python-oracledb, see the [installation instructions](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html) which will show you how to install on various operating systems.  For example on Windows:

```
python -m pip install oracledb --upgrade
```

Commonly all the various packages required for an application are put in a file called `requirements.txt`, one package per line e.g. :

```
oracledb
```

and then this can be distributed to users who can install via:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However if you are developing your own package, you would do it slightly differently and make all the packages you want to use dependencies for your package.  You would add this list to your package build, e.g like https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/v1.4.2/setup.cfg#L39 does with its `install_requires` line.  This specific line says that when a user installs oracledb, then the cryptography package is automatically installed as well.

Answer (score -2):

Developing a Python plugin for QGIS and managing dependencies like cx_Oracle is a common task. To ensure that the plugin works on client computers without requiring admin rights, you can follow these steps:

Virtual Environments:

Use virtual environments to isolate your project's dependencies. This helps prevent conflicts with system-wide packages and ensures that your plugin works on client machines.
You can create a virtual environment using venv or conda. I'll demonstrate using venv:

```
python -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate  # On Windows, use "myenv\Scripts\activate"
```

Install Dependencies:
Install the required packages (e.g., cx_Oracle) in the virtual environment.

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

Develop the Plugin:

Write and test your QGIS Python plugin within the virtual environment. Make sure it works as expected.
Packaging the Plugin:

To package your plugin for distribution, you can create a ZIP file or use the QGIS Plugin Builder or Plugin Reloader. These tools generate a directory structure for your plugin that includes a Python environment.
Include Dependencies:

Ensure that your dependencies are included with the plugin package. This is essential for users who may not have these dependencies installed.
Plugin Metadata:

Make sure to include metadata in your plugin to specify the required dependencies. This can be done in the plugin's metadata.txt file.
Installation Instructions:

Provide clear installation instructions to your users. Tell them to install QGIS, unzip the plugin package, and enable it in QGIS.
Testing on Client Machines:

Test your plugin on different client machines to ensure it works as expected without admin rights.
Distribution:

You can distribute your plugin via the QGIS Plugin Repository or by sharing the ZIP file. Users can install it from within QGIS.
Documentation and Support:

Consider creating documentation for your plugin, and provide a way for users to seek support or report issues (e.g., a GitHub repository or a dedicated forum).
Regarding tutorials and forums, the QGIS community is quite active, and you can find useful resources:

QGIS Python Plugin Development Documentation:
The official QGIS documentation has resources on plugin development: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html

QGIS Community Forum:
You can ask questions and find support on the QGIS community forum: https://community.qgis.org/

GitHub QGIS Repository:
You can explore existing QGIS plugins and their source code on GitHub to learn from examples: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-ResourceSharing

By following these steps and utilizing the QGIS community resources, you can create and distribute your Python plugin for QGIS.